# How to enable drop shadows under windows in Windows 10 1511?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-v1511

I took the Windows 10 December update - Version 1511 - today, and now drop-shadows are disabled under windows:

[image]

How can i re-enable drop-shadows under windows in Windows?